# Jar runs on host but fails in docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker, jar, docker-container

I have a `jar` which runs fine on my host; specifically, when I run

```
java -jar myjar.jar
```

I get the expected output:

> [2018-12-05 16:46:53.917] boot - 21252  INFO [main] --- Application: No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
>
> [2018-12-05 16:47:00.855] boot - 21252  INFO [main] --- Application: Started Application in 8.176 seconds (JVM running for 9.106)
>   This is the Core Data Micro Service.
>
> [2018-12-05 16:47:00.856] boot - 21252  INFO [main] --- Application: Registering to queue for events
>
> [2018-12-05 16:47:00.857] boot - 21252  INFO [main] --- ZeroMQEventSubscriber: Getting subscriber, listening to tcp://localhost:5565
>
> [2018-12-05 16:47:00.915] boot - 21252  INFO [main] --- ZeroMQEventSubscriber: Watching for new Event messages...

But then, I try to run the same `jar` inside a docker container. So I create the image like this:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
COPY myjar.jar /opt/spring-cloud/lib/
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/java"]
CMD ["-jar", "/opt/spring-cloud/lib/myjar.jar"]
EXPOSE 48080
```

and run it:

```
sudo docker run [ID]
```

but this time, I get this exception from the container logs (this is only a part of the exception because it is too big, but I can show it all if needed):

```
[2018-12-07 08:30:31.447] boot - 1  INFO [main] --- Application: No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default

[2018-12-07 08:32:35.423] boot - 1 ERROR [main] --- SpringApplication: Application startup failed

...

...

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'readingControllerImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.edgexfoundry.dao.ValueDescriptorRepository org.edgexfoundry.controller.impl.ReadingControllerImpl.valDescRepos; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'valueDescriptorRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 120000 ms while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{}. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 120000 ms while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{}. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)

...

...

Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 120000 ms while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{}. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]
    at com.mongodb.BaseCluster.getServer(BaseCluster.java:82)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getServer(DBTCPConnector.java:664)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.access$500(DBTCPConnector.java:40)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector$MyPort.getConnection(DBTCPConnector.java:513)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector$MyPort.get(DBTCPConnector.java:456)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getPrimaryPort(DBTCPConnector.java:415)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.createIndex(DBCollectionImpl.java:378)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.createIndex(DBCollection.java:597)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.createIndex(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:142)
    ... 57 more
```

Mongo has been started in another container through docker-compose (together with other services in other containers):

```
ps aux | grep mongo

root     16226  0.0  0.0   4340   768 ?        Ss   10:27   0:00 /bin/sh -c /edgex/mongo/config/launch-edgex-mongo.sh
root     16292  0.0  0.0   4340   764 ?        S    10:27   0:00 /bin/sh /edgex/mongo/config/launch-edgex-mongo.sh
root     16293  0.5  0.3 961168 61400 ?        SLl  10:27   0:05 mongod --smallfiles
```

This is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  volume:
    image: edgexfoundry/docker-edgex-volume:0.6.0
    container_name: edgex-files
    networks:
      - edgex-network
    volumes:
      - db-data:/data/db
      - log-data:/edgex/logs
      - consul-config:/consul/config
      - consul-data:/consul/data

  mongo:
    image: edgexfoundry/docker-edgex-mongo:0.6.0
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    container_name: edgex-mongo
    hostname: edgex-mongo
    networks:
      - edgex-network
    volumes:
      - db-data:/data/db
      - log-data:/edgex/logs
      - consul-config:/consul/config
      - consul-data:/consul/data
    depends_on:
      - volume

.... more services...

 networks:
   edgex-network:
     driver: "bridge
```

And the mongo db configuration properties:

```
spring.data.mongodb.username=core
spring.data.mongodb.password=password
spring.data.mongodb.database=coredata
#change to localhost when running locally during development 
# (or set hosts to point edgex-mongo to the mongo host
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
#spring.data.mongodb.host=edgex-mongo
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.connectTimeout=120000
spring.data.mongodb.socketTimeout=60000
spring.data.mongodb.maxWaitTime=120000
spring.data.mongodb.socketKeepAlive=true
```

Any ideas what may be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things going wrong here, first of all spring tries to connect to your mongodb on `localhost`, within docker this does not work since `localhost` references to the current container where of course no mongodb is available. To fix this you have to comment out this line and uncomment the next line which lists the host as `edgex-mongo` which corresponds with the hostname of your mongodb container, so spring knows to connect to that container.

However when you would do this you would run into the issue that it would not recognize `edgex-mongo` since it has no connection to this container. `edgex-mongo` is inside a bridged network which requires you to add the spring container to this network by using the following command:

`docker run --network edgex--network [image]`

I hope this helps you